# Django: How to automatically insert data everyday from Consumer_order to Daily_Cart?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Onece enter to place items into Customer_order. it has to automatically insert and save for every to save Daily_Cart.**

```
class Consumer_order(models.Model):
  name  = models.ForeignKey(Consumer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ac_no = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  newspaper = models.ManyToManyField(Newspaper,related_name="Consumer_ac_no")
  added_date = models.DateField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
    
  def __str__(self):
     return str(self.ac_no)


class Daily_Cart(models.Model):
      ac_no = models.ForeignKey(Consumer_order, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      newspaper = models.ManyToManyField(Consumer_order,related_name="Consumer_ac_no")
      added_date  = models.DateTimeField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
      
      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.added_date)
        
      def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
          date_object = datetime.date.today()
          crontab(minute=30, hour='7', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun')
          self.ac_no = self.Consumer_order.ac_no
          self.newspaper = self.Consumer_order.newspaper 
          super(Daily_Cart, self).start(*args, **kwargs)
          scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can write cron script.
It's pretty simple. Follow the steps as per below:

Install **APScheduler** python library.

`pip install APScheduler==3.6.3`

Create **updater.py** and **insert_data_script.py** in your Django-app (the same directory where model.py place)

Define a method in insert_data_script.py using which all the data of Consumer_order transfer to Daily_Cart. Let's call **transfer_daily_data** is method name

Define cron job in **updater.py**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .insert_data_script import transfer_daily_data


def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(transfer_daily_data, 'cron', hour=1) # This script will run every day on 1 am (UTC time)
    scheduler.start()
```

For more information, you can follow official [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: i did but little confused. data not insert

Comment: Can you add these both files in your question? So that I can check is there any mistake or not.

Comment: Here GitHub link https://github.com/Ravindrakumara/Newspaper_tracking/tree/master/Pro_Venv

Comment: Error message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445629/django-typeerror-deferredattribute-object-is-not-callable-while-every-day-t